# QueryTables.Add dynamic link referencing cells

Tags: excel, vba

The link I want to use is
"https://xxx/xxx/xxx/reporting?start_date=2022-05-15+00&end_date=2022-05-21+00" whereas the start_date=Simba1 and the end_date=Simba2

Simba 1 and simba 2 are date cells.

'Download Simba Table'

```
Sheets("SIMBA Data").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://xxx/xxx/xxx/reporting?" _
    & "start_date=" & Simba1 _
    & "&end_date=" & Simba2 & "", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "1"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Would help to explain what the problem is - what does it do instead of work?  Also include the declarations for Simba1/2 variables and where you assign them a value.  Likely you want to use something like `Format(Simba1,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "+00"` for each date.

Comment: This is webscraping a table, in this case it is table ID #1.  The Simba 1/2 variables are simply referencing cells F1 and F2 which are the dates that a user will enter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Format()`

```vb
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://xxx/xxx/xxx/reporting?" _
    & "start_date=" & Format(Simba1, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
    & "+00&end_date=" & Format(Simba2, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "+00", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
   
    '...
    '...
```

Comment: It hits and error at .Refresh BackgroundQuery:-False 

It says it is unable to open the link, but when looking at that link it doesn't seem to be inserting the contents of Simba1 and Simba2.   Is it just not referencing right?

Comment: Basically the cells referenced as SImba1 and Simba2 are not being put into the URL

Comment: As previously requested, please update your question to add the parts of your code where you declare and populate the Simba1/2 variables.

Comment: There is no code for it.  On "Report Controls" page, C1 is named as "Simba1", C2 is named as "Simba2", so they can be referenced in visual basic.   These two cells are populated with dates that will be updated daily.

Comment: I fixed it!! I apologize I am still learning.
I added the following and now it knows what to reference..  Thank you so much!!

Dim Simba1 As Variant
 
Simba1 = Range("'Report Controls'!$C$1").Value
 
 Dim Simba2 As Variant
 
Simba2 = Range("'Report Controls'!$C$2").Value

Comment: If you named your cells "simba1" and "simba2" then you should be able to use (eg) `Worksheets("Report Controls").Range("Simba1")` to reference them.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following with the answer that Tim posted, resolved my issue!!

```
Dim Simba1 As Variant

Simba1 = Range("'Report Controls'!$C$1").Value

Dim Simba2 As Variant

Simba2 = Range("'Report Controls'!$C$2").Value
```